# c# key access to another application

Tags: c#, window, sendkeys

I want to send keystrokes to another application. For example: I have opened a browser and I want write keystrokes to an opened notepad app without targeting notepad window. I just want for the browser window to be active the whole time.

Is it possible?

Comment: Sounds like a security hole if this was possible. Instead of writing to notepad, you could write to a cmd window and reformat the drive.

Answer (score 1):

If you really do mean sending keystrokes from a *web browser* to a running Windows application then this ***shouldn't*** be possible.

The reason is that web browsers are (or should be) sandboxed from the OS and other running applications to prevent undesirables from maliciously interfering with your computer via the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can, if you use the Windows API, however `SendInput` is the only one that will be guaranteed to do it properly, and only does so on the focused window. For other windows, you can use `SendMessage`, with `WM_KEYUP`, `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_CHAR`, but it's pretty unreliable. It's also usually undesirable behavior for an application to do this.